# Debian Slow Boot & Slow Login Time Screen

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

I'm using Debian 10 testing, The computer feels slow to boot. How can I speed it up?

> karemgmeay@KaremGmeay-Desktop:~$ systemd-analyze blame

> 36.524s apt-daily-upgrade.service
> 32.196s plymouth-quit-wait.service
> 18.171s udisks2.service
> 11.337s snapd.seeded.service
> 9.452s systemd-journal-flush.service
> 7.547s man-db.service
> 6.114s logrotate.service
> 6.052s dev-sda1.device
> 5.453s accounts-daemon.service
> 5.341s NetworkManager.service
> 5.116s polkit.service
> 4.352s avahi-daemon.service
> 4.262s switcheroo-control.service
> 3.920s wpa_supplicant.service
> 3.917s systemd-logind.service
> 3.914s ModemManager.service
> 2.460s preload.service
> 2.033s e2scrub_reap.service
> 2.004s rsyslog.service
> 1.883s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ff168ed4\x2d401b\x2d4913\x2dacc9\x2d07a0259feefe.service
> 1.717s gdm.service
> 1.677s systemd-udevd.service
> 1.596s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-36c15a82\x2d0fb8\x2d4a3e\x2da016\x2d5516a448b13c.service
> 1.388s apparmor.service
> 1.295s fwupd.service                                                                               790ms keyboard-setup.service
> 755ms home.mount
> 754ms
> dev-disk-by\x2duuid-80e3762b\x2dea3a\x2d4629\x2d88b3\x2d4026ca4d6c04.swap                   626ms networking.service
> 594ms user@1000.service
> 551ms systemd-sysusers.service
> 525ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
> 482ms pppd-dns.service
> 413ms systemd-random-seed.service
> 411ms systemd-sysctl.service
> 378ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
> 374ms plymouth-start.service

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment. Open your terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable ureadahead  
sudo systemctl disable ModemManager  
sudo systemctl disable plymouth  
sudo systemctl disable systemd.networkd.service
```

That should get your boot time to a reasonable number. You can try them one at a time, or all at once. If disabling any of them end up causing problems, you can simply reverse them with 'enable' instead of 'disable'.

With 'sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer', I'm not 100% certain if that's something that's needed to be disabled in this case, but it's better 'safe' than sorry.

That's the list of things I get rid of (with Lubuntu), plus the two at the top to address your longest process. Yes, it should still update and tell you when updates are available - it just won't be checking during the boot process. None of these *should* hose your system.

Anyhow, reboot and run `systemd-analyze blame` to see if it worked.